# How to resolve ACPI errors at shutdown?

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, acpi

When I turn off the laptop, the following messages appear on a black screen, from time to time:

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMB], AE_NOT_FOUND
ACPI Error: aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previos error (AE_NOT_FOUND)
```

In this case, the computer hangs for 3-4 minutes and then turns off. Pressing any key has no effect.

Comment: Have you made sure your BIOS/UEFI is up-to-date?

Comment: What is your HW configuration, we would prefer you posting `sudo inxi -Fxxxrz` output.

Comment: Haven't updated bios since purchase. The new firmware version was released a few months ago, according to the manufacturer's website. I'll try to update

Answer (score 0):

That may be a hardware problem (see the [ACPI wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACPI)), and not a Unix problem. You *may* be able to update the firmware to resolve the issue, but you'll have to look at the computer manufacturer's web site for instructions on how to do so with a machine that won't boot.